# how to safely execute multiple SELECT queries

Tags: javascript, cassandra, bluebird

In order to translate cassandra queries of type

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ... AND [param x] IN (val1, val2, ..., valN)
```

into multiple queries of type

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ... AND [param x] = val1
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ... AND [param x] = val2
...
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ... AND [param x] = valN
```

I have created the [function to translate array of parameters that contain arrays into all possible combinations of parameter values](https://jsfiddle.net/nikogamulin/wn9o3w0u/4/).

In some cases, several thousand of queries are generated. After trying to execute all queries using bluebird promises the following way:

```
Promise.all(promisesArray).then(function (results) { ... })
```

where promisesArray is the array of promises:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        client.execute(query, params, {prepare: true}, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

When trying to run batch of queries this way, there were several issues on cassandra and it didn't return the expected result.

Does anyone know how to safely execute multiple SELECT queries on cassandra, either by using promises or if there is a way to do it directly using cassandra driver?

Comment: What kind of issue appeared? What data C* returned?

Comment: When you call Promise.all(), if you have 1000 promises in that array then all of them will be called concurrently in a loop without waiting for the previous one to complete. Here that means 1000 DB calls in less than a second? Should that be a concern? You may use bluebird.map() to controll concurrency.

Comment: @Cortwave error:  uncaughtException: Maximum call stack size exceeded